# Making list items float for internet explorer 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

i want to make the items of two lists on a webpage to be located beside each other. I can easily do this with float:left and everything is working, despite our lovely Internet Explorer 8.

I read that the containing div should have a width and that, but nothing helped. I copied my code here and i would be grateful if someone has an idea why the float:left in the two ul-lists are not floated in IE8.

Full page code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ILBlz

Comment: Perhaps I am not sure what you had intended. You have applied the float to the LI tag, so each list item should float next to one another within the list. Were you looking for the items within the list to float? or the entire list to float?

The element you float needs to have a width specified and position:relative to play nice. Also, if you are going to apply display:block to the LI items, you will need a width to allow them to float since block will fill the container width by default.

Comment: What are the containers you want to see side by side ? codepen doesn't work in real IE8

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
footer .footer_left li {
   display: inline;
}
```

And just to help you: When *basic* positioning problems happen and something does not go well on a specific browser, pay attention to your markup's organization — there is a potential logic error here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for some reasons IE8 doesn't understand HTML5 tags.
remove them from CSS selectors.
and see rules applyied.

does this solves it :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.createElement('header');
 document.createElement('hgroup');
 document.createElement('nav');
 document.createElement('menu');
 document.createElement('section');
 document.createElement('article');
 document.createElement('aside');
 document.createElement('footer');
</script>
```

http://liveweave.com/dqNwK1 (to test in IE8 if server avalaible !! )

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem today and while searching the web I found your question
After a little experiment I found that any CSS rule you want to apply that contains an HTML5 tag will NOT be applied in IE8. I don't know why but when I tried to style a  tag IE8 didn't apply it and displayed a warning that I should enable compatibility mode in order to display pages that are DESIGN'ED FOR OLDER BROWSERS!!!!

That said, if you don't want to give up your HTML5 tags, structure & document outline, maybe you should try to target elements by ID, Classes or DOM order.

Comment: @GCyrillus
It's a good idea to use JS to create the elements but I wouldn't count on that since the user may have JavaScript disabled. What do you think ?